# How to conduct the object detection on sequence data/text (1D matrix)?

Tags: python, object-detection

I tried to search for some Keras codes for the object detection. But almost all of them deal with images. But what I want to do is to conduct object detection on sequence data/text. Here's the detail:

I have some sequences like this: (target region)(non-target region)(target region)(non-target region)...(target region)(non-target region). Both target region and non-target region are long sequences, but target region have their own special structures. I want the computer to learn the structure and the characteristics of 10,000 target region and detect the target sequences (print out the start and the end position of the target region) on new sequences.

Can anyone give me any instructions?

Here shows an example of object detection using RetinaNet:

https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet

Can anyone tell me how to revise the code to let it be able to deal with my problem?

Thank you very much!

Best,
Ying

Comment: All the 10000 target region can be seen as one class, instead of 10000 classes.